# My Rails 4.2.6 app uses two databases. Can I only use one for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, mongoid5

I have a web application in Rails 4.2.6 that was originally using MongoDB (through Mongoid 5) as its main database. However, now I need to connect to a MySQL database to only read some additional data for my app.

So far, I have required ActiveRecord in my project and was able to establish the connection with the aforementioned database in development environment. My configuration files for this matter are:

**mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mongo_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mongo_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_development
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

The problem arrives when I run my test suite. I am using RSpec and executing `bundle exec rspec spec` yields the following error message:

```
 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'test' database is not configured. Available: ["development"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

ActiveRecord complains for not having a test database to connect, but the problem is that I don't have a MySQL database for testing purposes: the specs I wrote only interact with Mongoid models.

I was considering creating an empty MySQL database as a hack, but I want to know first if I could configure ActiveRecord not to connect to a test database and use only `mongo_test`.

Is it possible to do what I want? Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question as the provided answers didn't fit my needs.

After many trials and errors I was able to avoid connecting to a MySQL database in *test* environment adapting the information given in this [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729840/how-do-i-selectively-disable-a-remote-db-connection-during-rspec-tests).

The only thing I needed to do was to add the following gem to my **Gemfile**:

```
group :test do
  gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'
end
```

This gem installs the [NullDB](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb) database adapter in the project, which enables ActiveRecord to establish a connection without the need to define a real database.

Last but not least, I updated my **config/database.yml** adding the parameters of a database connection in *test* environment that uses the new adapter:

```
test:
  adapter: nulldb
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_test
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here are two workarounds*

**Either: Add a sqlite database for your test env.**

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**Or: Move your autoload from `application.rb` to environment specific configs and move the `activerecord` gem to a `development` env on your `Gemfile`.**

*Gemfile*

```
group :development do
  gem 'activerecord'
end
```

*config/application.rb*:

- First: move this to `config/environments/test.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb` (keep in mind which models you want to exclude from the `test` env, i.e. the `activerecord` mo

  ```
  config.autoload_paths += WHATEVER
  ```

Remove `require 'rails/all'` line and require frameworks you want to use specifically in each environment file too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm trying to apply the second workaround you stated, but I encountered some problems with the autoloading of `activerecord` models. It seems like `config.autoload_paths` variable cannot be modified in the environment-specific files, as it's mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Comment: Check this answer about `config.eager_load_paths`  and how it acts different between development and production http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773266/confusing-about-autoload-paths-vs-eager-load-paths-in-rails-4 , I think it will be useful.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Mohamed! I was able to isolate the loading of my `activerecord` models and the require of `activerecord`'s railtie in _config/application.rb_ using conditions like `require 'active_record/railtie' unless Rails.env.test?` and `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'antifraud', '**/')] unless Rails.env.test?`. Currently, when I run my specs they all fail returning the same error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base` Does this error make sense to you? Would you know how to solve it?